# Can't understand this simple JavaScript code behavior

Tags: javascript

The following function make_f(n) attempting to return a function such that when the user call it, it prints the numbers n, n-1, .., 0.

The logic is to try build the return function (f) with every iteration
but it just print "1" infinity. Why is that and how should I fix it?
Thanks.

(You can think of 'write(i)' as 'console.log(i)' if you want.)

```
function make_f(n) {
  var i;
  var f;
  f = function () { write("0");};
  for (i = 1; i <= n ; i++) {
    f = function () { write(i.toString()); f();};
  }
  return f;
}
make_f(10)();
```

Comment: Step through it line by line in a debugger.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I ment short by 'simple'

Comment: @EranDavid Say what you mean then

Comment: "Simple" and "short" are not synonyms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a closure over the last function and the value. This creates an inner scope and it has only the values at creating time of the functions.

```js
function make_f(n) {
    var i,
        f = function () { console.log(0); };
    
    for (i = 1; i <= n ; i++) {
        f = function (f, i) {
            return function () {
                console.log(i);
                f();
            };
        }(f, i);
    }
    return f;
}

make_f(10)();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that `f()` would still reference its previous function "version" is invalid because both `f` and `i` are defined in the *function scope* (using `var`), hence by returning from the outer-most function (as well as inside the loop), `f` already points to itself and you're ending-up nowhere.

If you'll use `let` instead, your code will work as expected (although it's not a recommended way to achieve whatever is it you're trying to achieve):

```
function make_f(n) {
  var f = function() { console.log(0); };

  for (let i = 1; i <= n ; i++) {
    let prev = f;
    f = function () { console.log(i); prev();};
  }

  return f;
}

make_f(10)();
```

Answer (score 0):

if i'm not mistaken by your logic, you can use yield to accomplishe what you need.

```
function make_f(n) {
  let i;
  let f = function* (){
    for (i = 1; i <= n ; i++){
      yield console.log(i.toString());
    }
  }
  return f();
}
let x = make_f(10);
x.next();
```